# Optimal Control to Maximise a Variable Specified as Constant Forever

Tags: optimization, optimal-control

The following is a problem which arises in the economics of natural resources, but I’m posting it here as my question is essentially mathematical:

> Output $Y$ is produced according to a function $Y = F(K,rS)$ where $K$ is
>   man-made capital, $S$ is a non-renewable natural resource, and $r$ is the
>   proportionate rate of extraction and use of the natural resource ($K,S,r \geq 0$). 
>   Part of output is consumed ($C$), and the remainder adds to man-made
>   capital.  Given initial stocks of capital $K_0$ and resource $S_0$, what is
>   the maximum *constant* level of consumption that can be sustained
>   *forever*, and what are the associated time paths of $K$ and $S$?

Trying to write this as an optimal control problem, it is simple enough to identify $r_t$ as a control variable, $K_t$ and $S_t$ as state variables, and two state equations:

$$\frac{dK_t}{dt}  =  F(K_t,r_tS_t) – C_t$$
$$\frac{dS_t}{d_t} = - r_tS_t$$

The difficult part is to specify a suitable objective function.

**Option 1**:  Take C to be constant and maximise C:

$$\max_r C$$

This does not fit the standard form of an optimal control problem as the objective function has no time dimension.

**Option 2**:  Maximise the sum to infinity of $C$, adding an additional state equation $dC_t/dt = 0$ to ensure constancy of $C$:
$$\max_r \int_0^{\infty} C_t dt$$

This has the consequence that if $C > 0$ then the value of the integral will be infinite.

**Option 3**:  Treat $C$ as if it were given and *minimise* the sum to infinity of $r_tS_t$.

$$\min_r \int_0^{\infty} r_tS_t dt$$

Then (in outline) having identified conditions in terms of $C$ that solve this minimisation problem, find the value of $C$ such that the value of the above integral equals $S_0$.  This approach (which is used in [Solow (1974)](http://folk.uio.no/gasheim/zSol1974.pdf) p 35) is the only one I have found workable.

**Question**: Can the problem be solved by a more direct approach along the lines of Options 1 or 2 above?